# SharePoint 2013 remove title in webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

How to remove or hide title page in sharepoint webpart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edit the Web Part, and put a blank space in the "Title" field (in "Appearance" section).

See below.

[image: Blank Space]

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution:
Add some spaces in the Title field of the Web Part Properties.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
      document.querySelector("#pageTitle").style.display = 'none';
})();
</script>




I found the solution guys.. with that javascript code..

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit WebPart --> Appearance --> Change the chrome type to Border Only

Click on "OK" and save the Page

Then title of the webpart will not be visible.

Hope this helps you

Comment: This just hides the controls in the web part (like the "New Document" link). The Title is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide a page title by using CSS or JavaScript.

JavaScript :

```
document.querySelector("#pageTitle").style.display = 'none';
```

In CSS :

```
#pageTitle
{
   display:none;
}
```

You can add on you page a "Script Editor WebPart", an add the above line of JS or CSS in the code sniped of the webpart.

Answer (score 0):

In the edit webpart settings of your webpart, select the Chrome type to "None" from the dropdown. Apply and Save your changes. This will remove the Title and its associated space

**Edit Webpart --> Appearance --> Chrome Type --> None**

Comment: Chrome type to "None" is the way to go, out of the box functionality.

Comment: Not, that still shows the Title...